# SQL DATEPART(qq, @date) date quarter start October

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that prints the data grouped quarter, the query uses `datepart(qq,repo.lesson_date)` SQL function.

My issue is I want my first quarter to be October-December and not Jan-March like the output I get from the SQL function above.

Is there anyone can assist?

Comment: Just remove 9 months from the date first then. October - 9 months = January = 1st Quarter.

Comment: Please attach here your select query so we can help you solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use an additional calculation (`DATEPART(qq, repo.lesson_date) % 4 + 1`) as a possible option.

Example:

```
SELECT 
   DATEPART(qq, lesson_date) AS [Quarter], 
   DATEPART(qq, lesson_date) % 4 + 1 AS [NewQuarter]
FROM (VALUES
   ('20210101'),
   ('20210401'),
   ('20210701'),
   ('20211001')
) repo (lesson_date)
```

Result:

```
Quarter NewQuarter
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just adding 3 months to the date:

```
datepart(quarter, dateadd(month, 3, repo.lesson_date))
```